# Eliminating minor crests/troughs in a tidal curve

Tags: curves, wavelets

I have some tidal data, I only have the turning points of the curve.

I want to eliminate the minor troughs/crests so I only get the high and low tide without the minor variations.

[The curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4WAa8.jpg)

Is there a good method for this?

My curve is not a fixed length or amplitude and its important I keep the actual high and lows.

I will be trying implementing it in code to filter the data

Comment: You mean like a high-pass filter for the frequency?

Comment: maybe, Im not sure, I'll take a look at high-pass filters though thanks

Comment: it seems a high pass filter would be ok but how would I work out what value is required to filter out the items I want. I think thats the main crux of my problem, I want this to work with waves that have very different values so I need a method of working out a working filter value for each set of data.